# Perl: Retrieving Hash values in order they were created

Tags: perl, hash

I've a hash of array. When I trying to retrieve them the values in the array are not being printed according to the order of the corresponding hash keys. I've used 
both 'Tie::IxHash::Easy' and  'Tie::Autotie 'Tie::IxHash' to tie the hash.

For example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::IxHash::Easy;

tie my  %idAlignment, 'Tie::IxHash::Easy';

@{$idAlignment{1}{r1}} = qw/4032.82 4145.04 4519.05 4527.46 5144.13/;
@{$idAlignment{1}{t1}} = qw/4032.86 4144.92 4519.11 - -/;

printAlnCols($idAlignment{1},0);

sub printAlnCols{
    my($alnRef,$colIndex)=@_;
    my %Aln=%{$alnRef};
    foreach my $k(keys %Aln ){
        print $Aln{$k}[$colIndex],"\n";;    
    }

}
```

The script prints 4032.86 and 4032.82, whereas I expect it to print 4032.82 followed by 4032.86 as the $idAlignment{1}{r1}} was created  before $idAlignment{1}{t1}.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks!!! Is there any Perl module to do that ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? I mean, one approach is to use an array of keys (or sort) if you're doing something that needs ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your only problem is that you are making a copy of the ordered hash into a new unordered hash %Aln.  Just use the reference instead:

```
sub printAlnCols {
    my ($alnRef,$colIndex) = @_;
    foreach my $k(keys %$alnRef){
        print $alnRef->{$k}[$colIndex],"\n";;
    }
}
```